# Sklearn - How to add custom stopword list from txt file

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I already done the TFIDF using Sklearn but the problem is I can't used english words for stopwords coz mine is in Bahasa Malaysia (non english). What I need is to import my txt file that contain a list of stopwords.

stopword.txt

```
saya
cintakan
awak
```

tfidf.py

```
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer
corpus = ['Saya benci awak',
          'Saya cinta awak',
          'Saya x happy awak',
          'Saya geram awak',
          'Saya taubat awak']
vocabulary = "taubat".split()
vectorizer = TfidfVectorizer(analyzer='word', vocabulary=vocabulary)
X = vectorizer.fit_transform(corpus)
idf = vectorizer.idf_
print dict(zip(vectorizer.get_feature_names(), idf))
```

Comment: Why not preprocess your corpus and just remove these stopwords yourself before running it over `TFIDFVectorizer`?

Comment: this is just an example. the real one is really contain a lot of words. just for your understanding only.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can load your list of specific stop words and pass it as a parameter to the `TfidfVectorizer`. In your example:

```
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer
corpus = ['Saya benci awak',
          'Saya cinta awak',
          'Saya x happy awak',
          'Saya geram awak',
          'Saya taubat awak']

# HERE YOU DO YOUR MAGIC: you open your file and load the list of STOP WORDS
stop_words = [unicode(x.strip(), 'utf-8') for x in open('stopword.txt','r').read().split('\n')]

vectorizer = TfidfVectorizer(analyzer='word', stop_words = stop_words)
X = vectorizer.fit_transform(corpus)
idf = vectorizer.idf_
print dict(zip(vectorizer.get_feature_names(), idf))
```

Output with stop_words:

```
{u'taubat': 2.09861228866811, u'happy': 2.09861228866811, u'cinta': 2.09861228866811, u'benci': 2.09861228866811, u'geram': 2.09861228866811}
```

Output without stop_words param:

```
{u'benci': 2.09861228866811, u'taubat': 2.09861228866811, u'saya': 1.0, u'awak': 1.0, u'geram': 2.09861228866811, u'cinta': 2.09861228866811, u'happy': 2.09861228866811}
```

> **Warning**: I wouldn't use the param `vocabulary` because it is telling the `TfidfVectorizer` to only pay attention to the words specified in it and it's usually harder to be aware of all words that you want to take into account than saying the ones you want to dismiss. So, if you remove the `vocabulary` param from your example and you add the `stop_words` param with your list it will work as you expect.

Answer (score 0):

In Python3, I recommend the following process for ingesting your own stop word lists:

1. Open relevant file path and read the stop words stored in .txt as a list:

```
with open('C:\\Users\\mobarget\\Google Drive\\ACADEMIA\\7_FeministDH for Susan\\Stop words Letters_improved.txt', 'r') as file:
    my_stopwords=[file.read().replace('\n', ',')]
```

2. Refer to your stop words in the vectorizer:

```py
vectorizer = text.CountVectorizer(input='filename', stop_words=my_stopwords, min_df=20)
```